# how to insert a new empty line on selected index number in an array using \n. while we loop through it using v-for and create a list

Tags: vue.js

want to insert a new empty line before a selected array element while we loop through it using v-for to create a list..trying to do this using \n isn't working

```
<!-- this is the template part -->
<ul>   
    <li v-for = "ninja in ninjas" > {{ninja}}</li>  
</ul>


/* this is the script part notice index no 2 in the array*/

data() {
    return {
        ninjas: [
            'mati kahe kumhaar sey, tu kya ronday mohey', 
            ' Ik din aisa aayega mai rondungi tohe',
            '\n aaye hain toh jaayengay Raja, Rank, fkeer', 
            ' Ik sinhaasan chodi chale, Ik baandhay zanjeer'
        ]
    };
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do using the `<pre>` tag which forces it to preserve white space, new lines, etc. This is often used for preserving formatting in code examples.

```
 <div id="app">
   <ul>   
     <li v-for = "ninja in ninjas" ><pre>{{ninja}}</pre></li>  
   </ul>
</div>
```

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/10yL6va8/8/

You will probably want to use css to style the text surrounded by `<pre>` since most browsers automatically format it differently.

Comment: brother this is not working as in another code i have multiline elements and it is not accepting multiline elements as a string.. what so ever is in the same line it accepts as string.

Comment: I see one will have to use `` instead of " " or ' ' for multiline strings..